# Descendants() doesn't work. WinRT and HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, parsing, windows-runtime

Can u help me?
I'm trying to parse html page.
Parsing "div" tags works fine.

I need this block of html code:

```
<td class="like">Some text</td>
```

This should work, but it doesnt:

```
var getLikes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(d => d.Attributes["class"] != null && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("like"));
foreach (var item in getLikes)
{
    Likes.Text = item.InnerText;
}
```

Also notice, that this one doesn't work too:

```
var getLikes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").Where(d => d.Attributes["class"] != null && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("like"));
foreach (var item in getLikes)
{
    Likes.Text = item.InnerText;
}
```

So, any ideas?

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Errors? More information

Comment: @Tseng
No errors, Likes.Text is empty.